# Unable to read input in bash script on github actions

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, github, github-actions

I am facing an issue with reading the input from GitHub actions.

I have created a cli in which I need to provide some input while executing since I don't want to interact with the cli and provide the input directly in the command. I am using '<' for providing it.

I have tried below options but none of them works in github actions (all of them work fine in my local environment).

1. `my-cli <<< name`
2. `my-cli < name.txt`
   (where name.txt contains the name)
3. `printf name | my-cli`
4. `cat name.txt | my-cli` 
   (where name.txt contains the name)

Assuming, my-cli expects some string (name).

I tested all these in my local Ubuntu, it works fine but not with GitHub actions.

my workflow.yml file

```
# This is a basic workflow that is manually triggered

name: Some name
on:
    schedule:
        - cron: "0 0 * * *"
    workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
    solve:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
            - name: Checkout
              uses: actions/checkout@v2
            - name: Apply permissions
              run: chmod +x scripts/*.sh
            - name: Setup
              env: 
                  name: ${{ vars.USERNAME }}
              run: scripts/setup.sh
              shell: bash
```

my setup.sh file

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $username
echo -e "$creds" >> auth.txt
# cat auth.txt | leetcode user -c   
my-cli < auth.txt
# my-cli <<< $username 
rm auth.txt
```

The output is empty
name:
But it should have
name: someName
upon execution.

Can someone please let me know if I am missing something? It works fine with local env

Comment: You don't show the implementation of `my-cli`. Is it ensured that it reads standard input?

Comment: In your workflow, you're only setting `name` env var but in the script you're using `username` and `creds` too. Where are they coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to set Github Action secret first.

(Github > Settings > Security > Secrets and variables > Actions)

After that, you can retrieve them by specifying `${{ secrets.<your_secret_name> }}`

So, in the `Setup` step, maybe can do something like this:

```
  - name: Setup
    env: 
      name: ${{ vars.USERNAME }}
    shell: bash
    run: |
      echo "env.name: ${{ env.name }}"
      echo "whoami: $(whoami)"
      echo ${{ secrets.creds }} | leetcode user -c
```